# Xcode Automated UI testing log memory usage

Tags: ios, memory, profiler, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

Is there a way with the JavaScript framework that Apple gives the developer to log memory usage. I know you can add Instruments to look at the memory usage but I want to be able to log memory usage in the Trace Log after certain actions.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a bunch of templates together in instruments. In your case, it would be the UI Automation template + the Allocation/Leak template (depending whether you wanna analyze allocations or leak). Hope this helps.

Comment: instruments -w device-udid -t Automation.tracetemplate -t Leaks.tracetemplate testapp.app -e UIASCRIPT testscript_device.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp

I'm using above command pass to multiple template. But it's throwing below error : Instruments Usage Error : Multiple templates specified

Can you guide me how to pass multiple template?